# How to validate a role with devise gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Im trying to validate a enum with the gem devise, but it doesn't save in my active record.

this is my model:
class User < ApplicationRecord

```
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  validates :full_name, presence: true
  enum role: %i[admin_user regular_user]
```

end

this is my controller:

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

```
 before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |user_params|
      user_params.permit({ roles:[] }, :full_name,:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
  end
```

end

and this is my views:

### Sign up

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email%><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>
  <div class= "field">
    <%= f.label :full_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :full_name, autocomplete: "full_name"%>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%=f.label :roles %>
    <%= f.select :role, collection: User.roles.keys.to_a %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

What should i change to save the roles in active record?

Comment: On a side note - in Ruby by convention any hash options should be placed at the end of the arguments lists and you can drop the brackets. While it might not matter in this case the code would brake if Devise where ever to switch to real keyword arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You're whitelisting an array when you just need a single param:

```
protected
 
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |user_params|
    user_params.permit(:role, :full_name,:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

You should also fix the view so that you're using the same argument for the label and input:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :role %>
  <%= f.select :role, collection: User.roles.keys.to_a %>
</div>
```

This is important for assistive technologies such as screenreaders so that they can properly link the label to the input via the `for` attribute.